# replacing "hardcopy" with Octave function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, frame, octave, video-processing

I'm trying to create some video in Octave.  I have a matlab file that works to do what I want, but i'm trying to get it to work in Octave.  Basically the function 'hardcopy' is an undocumented matlab function used in this code and I'd like to replace it with something octave-friendly.

I found a reverse-solution here (someone trying to use hardcopy): http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-3NMHJ5/?solution=1-3NMHJ5

but I'm a super novice in terms of matlab and octave, so while option 2 of that solution looks like it will work (i think octave has the imread functions) I don't know what to change about the code I have (I didn't write it, and, as I said, I don't know matlab).  The code is

```
    % add this frame to movie file
    %mov = addframe(mov,gcf);
    renderer = get(hnd,'renderer');
    if strcmp(renderer,'painters')
        renderer = 'opengl';
    end
    set(hnd, 'Units', 'pixels');
    pixelsperinch = get(0,'screenpixelsperInch');

    frame = hardcopy(hnd, ['-d' renderer], ['-r' num2str(round(pixelsperinch))]);
    addframe(mov,frame);
```

Does anyone know how to swap out that hardcopy function for an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a satisfying solution, but you could use the higher-level [`print`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html) command to save individual frames to files. Have a look at the partial code examples on pages 91–93 in [this PDF presentation](http://srl.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/downloadsdir/Octave-Matlab-Tutorial.pdf). The frames could then be assembled into a movie using other tools (e.g., ffmpeg [as is done here](http://lnotestoself.blogspot.com/2010/03/making-movie-in-octave.html)).

For a more efficient frame grabbing solution you'll have to go to OpenGL (which is what `hardcopy` is doing). [This thread](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/getframe-alternatives-td3874405.html) suggests some starting points, but may need to write C/C++ code.

Comment: I don't quite understand the 'frames/frame%04d.png' of fname = sprintf('frames/frame%04d.png',i);  in the PDF presentation.  And do you know what parts of my code I would replace with the code from the pdf?  Sorry i'm really a super novice with matlab and octave, thanks so much for your help though!!

Comment: As I mentioned, this is not a drop in solution – `hardcopy` is undocumented after all – and Octave doesn't appear to have something like Matlab's `getframe`. You're going to have to read some of the documentation, figure stuff out, and maybe come back to StackOverflow and ask specific questions when something doesn't seem to work. The `sprintf` command you asked is just creating numbered file names like: 'frames/frame0000.png', 'frames/frame0001.png', 'frames/frame0002.png', etc. Try it out and you'll see. These file name strings are then passed to the `print` function to write PNG files.

Comment: gotcha, thanks much for the clarification!  I'll give it a shot and then return!